# Is it possible to keep the indexing of a project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, indexing

I haven't used eclipse in a long time, and I'm not very familiar with it, so this question may sound silly. I have a big project, and indexing takes a long time in eclipse. The problem is every time I close eclipse, I should rebuild the indexer. This process takes more than 3 or 4 hours, and I don't want to keep eclipse open all the time. Is it possible to not need reindexing after closing eclipse?

Comment: What do you mean by *"I **should** rebuild the indexer"*?

Comment: I would imagine that this depends on a number of factors, too - the size of your project, the processor speed and amount of memory on your machine, whether or not you use a hard disk which spins or an SSD...

Comment: @Andreas I mean the size of the project is too big, and I would like to have the indexing work. so every time I close and reopen eclipse, I need to rebuild the indexer, am I not right?

Comment: @Makoto maybe my post wasn't clear, I'm actually not asking about reducing the time of indexing, but if it is possible to avoid rebuilding the indexer.

Comment: Why do you believe **you** need to rebuild the indexer? If no files used by the Eclipse project was modified outside of Eclipse, you don't *need* to do anything. I'm not even sure what you mean by "rebuild the indexer", but if you modify files outside of Eclipse, then you select the files in Eclipse and select "Refresh", which will recompile/reindex/reXXX whatever is needed for those files only. You need to do that regardless of whether Eclipse was open or closed when the files were modified.

Comment: I would imagine that indexing your project ahead of time makes certain functions more convenient and quicker to run.  I don't know Eclipse that well - I use IntelliJ instead - but I imagine it's similar enough in that the specs of your computer have a direct impact on why it's taking so long.  Conversely, are you looking for a way to simply disable the index operation?

Comment: well you're right, I do not rebuild it, but eclipse automatically starts the indexer when reopened(even if I didn't modify any files outside it). Though I was looking for a way to save the state of the indexing for next times I open the project in eclipse.@Andreas